# Looping through a json object in react js file

Tags: json, reactjs, create-react-app

I have my json object array as

```
 {
  "_index": [
    "houseid"
  ], 
  "added": [
    {
      "description": "detail about column", 
      "houseid": "la 123", 
      "\ufeffID": "154"
    }, 
    {
      "description": "detail about column", 
      "houseid": "la 123", 
      "\ufeffID": "154"
    }, 
    {
      "description": "detail about column", 
      "houseid": "la 123", 
      "\ufeffID": "154"
    }, 
    {
      "description": "detail about column", 
      "houseid": "la 123", 
      "\ufeffID": "154"
    }
  ], 
  "changed": [], 
  "removed": [
    {
      "description": "detail about column", 
      "houseid": "la 123", 
      "\ufeffID": "154"
    }, 
    {
      "description": "detail about column", 
      "houseid": "la 123", 
      "\ufeffID": "154"
    }, 
    {
      "description": "detail about column", 
      "houseid": "la 123", 
      "\ufeffID": "154"
    }, 
    {
      "description": "detail about column", 
      "houseid": "la 123", 
      "\ufeffID": "154"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to apply a loop so i can present details for added, removed changed as below: 
       description            houseid   effid
       detail about column    la 123    154
       detail about column    la 123    154

Answer (score 0):

just import with some name, and get what you want.

```
import data from '../../result/result.json';

/* somewhere */
let to-add = data.toadd; // get field what you want.
```

Comment: yes i cant access to-add as to-add = data.toadd

Comment: but i want to iterate it in a loop so i can  publish it in a table under <tr> and <td> tag for toadd, removed, changed

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to use the [forEach](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach) method of the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) library. It will give you freedom to loop over the keys of objects as well.

```
_.forEach(object, (value, key) => {
    //do operations on value and key
})
```

If you need to render in react by looping over elements, you probably want to do something like this:

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
        {_.map(elements, (item) => {
            <div>{item.name}</div>
        })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

You can make this work for table too. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442544/2648216) answer as well.

Comment: i have updated the question. and map is not recognized in my table.component.js