# react native render foreach loop

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I ran forEach inside the render block and it outputs normally on the
console, but the text tag is not displayed on the output.

What is the problem?

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

class Lotto extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      count: 6,
      maxNum: 45
    };

    this.lottoSet = this.createLottoNumber();
  }

  createLottoNumber() {
    let lottoSet = new Set();
    let rNum;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.count; i++) {
      rNum = Math.round(Math.random() * (this.state.maxNum * 1) + 1);
      if (lottoSet.has(rNum)) i--;
      else lottoSet.add(rNum);
    }

    return lottoSet;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.lottoSet.forEach(n => {
          console.log(`<Text style={styles.item}>${n.toString()}</Text>`);
          return <Text style={styles.item}>{n.toString()}</Text>;
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#333",
    flexDirection: "row",
    paddingTop: "10%",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  item: {
    color: "#fff",
    textAlign: "center",
    width: "100px"
  }
});

export default Lotto;
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442462/reactjs-map-works-but-foreach-doesnt.  Don't worry this is a very common mistake people make.  Including me 5 years ago, you can check my questions back in 2015.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use map instead to render elements.

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.lottoSet.map(n => (
          <Text key={n.toString()} style={styles.item}>{n.toString()}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

React is declarative and takes a declaration of view state to render, map will build a declared, immutable view state.  Whereas using forEach has potential to create side effects outside of the render method, thus is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

`forEach` does not return a value, but stands for executing side effects on each array element.
Instead, you are looking for `map`:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {this.lottoSet.map(n => {
      console.log(`<Text style={styles.item}>${n.toString()}</Text>`);
      return <Text key={n.toString()} style={styles.item}>{n.toString()}</Text>;
    })}
  </View>
```

Also, note that I add a `key` prop to each `Text` element, you can read about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

BTW, the fact that you called `createLottoSet` in the constructor once, meaning that it won't be generated on every change of state.